# AppleTV OTT app not showing "Play" button on the build

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, ott

I'm very new to X Code.. but I'm having trouble figuring out why the "play" button is not showing up on the screen (over the top of a background image) after a successful build of the app in ContentView. Ultimately, I'd like to position the button to a specific area on the screen and have the button launch a video that is hosted on Cloudflare. But, at the moment, I cannot seem to get the button to show up on screen. I get the background to show up after a successful build.. but nothing else. I've tried to use storyboard to drag and drop a button but even that fails to show up. I'm so new to this that I'm getting easily stalled.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  
//
// 
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreData

import UIKit
import AVKit

import TVUIKit
    
struct
contentview: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                // What the button does
            }) {
                // How the button looks like
                Text("PLAY")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding(10)
                    .frame(minWidth: 100)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .fill(Color.gray)
                )
            }.buttonStyle(.plain) // Prevents the automatic style
    

            Image("SedonaNowCenterBGwtxt") .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            
  

    
            
        }
    }
    
struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            contentview()
                .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
                .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
                .previewDevice("Apple TV 4K (3rd generation) (at 1080p)")
        }
    }
}

struct Previews_SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("SedonaNowCenterBGwtxt") .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        }
    }
}



//import AVKit
//import TVUIKit

extension AVPlayerViewController {
    // Configure 16:9 UICollectionView cell
    
    
    
    
    
    struct myView: View {
        // Change the url to the Cloudflare Stream HLS manifest URL
        private let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: )!)
        
        var body: some View {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .onAppear() {
                    player.play()
                }
        }
    }
    
    struct myView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            myView()
        }
    }
}
```